# Telephone permutation question using recursion / backtracking

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I came up with my own solution to the following leetcode problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/

Official Solution: https://leetcode.com/articles/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/

When I looked at the most common solutions, I see everyone builds the final string from beginning to end, so they'll append A, then AB, then finally ABC.
The approach I went with goes from bottom up, so the recursive calls would build up C, then BC, then the final step does A + BC. In other words, I would build the latter part of the string first and append the current character in the front.

Can anyone comment if my "reverse" approach would still be correct or are there any logical flaws ? Are there any pros/cons to my approach ? Thanks!

```
class Solution(object):
    def letterCombinations(self, digits):
        """
        :type digits: str
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        """ input 23 """
        lookup = {'2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'], '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'], '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'],
                 '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'], '7' : ['p','q','r', 's'], '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'], '9': ['w', 'x','y','z']
                 }
        myList = self.create(digits, 0, lookup)
        return myList

    def create(self, digits, index, lookup):

        finalList = []
        if digits is None or digits == '':
            return []

        if index == len(digits) -1:
            return lookup[digits[index]]

        currentSet = lookup[digits[index]]
        for currentChar in currentSet:
            perms = self.create(digits, index + 1, lookup)
            for perm in perms:
                finalList.append( currentChar + perm)
        return finalList
```

Comment: Does this pass leetcode? I don't see what difference it makes which direction you work. The only con with working backwards is it's less intuitive.

Comment: @ggorlen - Yep, this passes leetcode. I was just wondering if i'm thinking about the problem wrong if i went the reverse way.

Comment: No, you aren't although just like writing any loop backwards, it begs the question why not just do it forwards, so it's sort of a code smell. Most code only iterates backwards if there's a concrete reason to do it. Very minor though.